# Tab content isn't displaying in a fixed position

Tags: html, css, tabs, accordion

I'm working on a responsive tab element, based on [this pen](https://codepen.io/gsarig/pen/GWgNdx), which displays as an accordion on mobile devices (tablet and smaller size screens - break width is 800px).  I'm about 98% of where I want to be, but I cannot figure out why my active tab content isn't displaying in a fixed position at the top of the content area.  I'd like all of the content to begin displaying at the same point vertically. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```css
.tabbed-content {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #ccc;
    max-width: 1100px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.tabs ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.tabs ul li {
    background: #eee;
}

.tabs ul li a {
    padding: .5em 1em;
}

.tabs ul li a:hover,
.tabs ul li a.active {
    background: #444;
    color: #eee;
}

.item {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.item::before {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #eee;
    padding: .5em;
    display: block;
}

.item.active::before {
    background: #444;
    color: #eee;
}

.item.active .item-content {
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .item.active .item-content {
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    .tabs-side .tabs li {
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
}

.tabbed-content .tabs {
    display: none;
}

.tabbed-content .item {
    min-height: 2em;
}

.tabbed-content .item::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
}

.tabbed-content .item .item-content {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.tabbed-content .item.active .item-content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    min-height: 195px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .tabbed-content .tabs {
        display: block;
    }
    .tabbed-content .tabs li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabbed-content .tabs li a {
        display: block;
    }
    .tabbed-content .item {
        min-height: 0;
    }
    .tabbed-content .item::before {
        display: none;
    }
    .tabbed-content.tabs-side .tabs {
        width: 250px;
        float: left;
    }
    .tabbed-content.tabs-side .tabs li {
        display: block;
    }
    .tabbed-content.tabs-side .item {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 799px) {
    .tabbed-content .item.active .item-content {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<article class="tabbed-content tabs-side">
    <nav class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#side_tab1" class="active">Design &amp; Construction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#side_tab2">Operations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#side_tab3">Energy Efficiency</a></li>
            <li><a href="#side_tab4">Reliability</a></li>
            <li><a href="#side_tab5">Connectivity</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="side_tab1" class="item active" data-title="Design &amp; Construction">
        <div class="item-content">
            <p>Long form content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="side_tab2" class="item" data-title="Operations">
        <div class="item-content"><p>Long form content</p></div>
    </section>
    <section id="side_tab3" class="item" data-title="Energy Efficiency">
        <div class="item-content">
            <p>Long form content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="side_tab4" class="item" data-title="Reliability">
        <div class="item-content">
            <p>Long form content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="side_tab5" class="item" data-title="Connectivity">
        <div class="item-content">
            <p>Long form content</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because or your Javascript sets items to be closed or your CSS is saying close all items. Because you didn't placed any Javascript code I will give you a CSS solution.

```css
.tabbed-content .item .item-content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
}
    
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .tabbed-content .item .item-content {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

This must do the trick for you. For a visual example: https://codepen.io/fijnzijn/pen/vYLPbEZ.

Comment: I did not put any JS in because it's not relative to the issue I'm facing.  The JS simply adds and removes the "active" class which causes the tabs to open and close.  It doesn't impact the vertical placement of the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

I dug into this a bit more with dev tools and I came up with a solution that seems to work.  This may not be the best or only solution, but I don't see any performance issues with it at this point.

I added the following to the media query for min-width:800px in my prior code.

```
    section .item.active {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:60px;
    margin-right:30px;
}

article { min-height:370px; }
```